# list representing character error

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to know if I can add here names instead of numbers, to display them further in the textbox:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<int> names = new List<int>();
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            nmstxtbx.Text = "";

            combo_list.Items.Add("Ahmed");
            names.Add("Atef");

            combo_list.Items.Add("Omar");
            names.Add(5000);

            combo_list.Items.Add("Mohamed");
            names.Add(4000);
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void combo_list_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            nmstxtbx.Text = names[combo_list.SelectedIndex].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

So please am a real noob here, can anyone help, also I was asking what I have to write if I want to create a combo box with some names in it, and want to allow the user to type one of the entries and when he presses enter, the name disappears, can anyone help me with that ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve but:

`names.Add("Atef")` - wont works because `names` is `int` type - you have to change it to

```
List<string> names = new List<string>()
```

For removing an item by entering it into textbox use:

```
 private void nmstxtbx_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
            {
                if (combo_list.Items.Contains(nmstxtbx.Text))
                    combo_list.Items.Remove(nmstxtbx.Text);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need Names and their Number to be related to each other it is much easier to have a class that hold this info together, for example a `NameDTO` class that holds an `Id` and a `Name`.

```
public class NameDTO
{
    public int   Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can now use a list of that class in your form to hold all the names:

```
List<NameDTO> names = new List<NameDTO>();
```

In the form load event you fill your List and assign it to the `Datasource` of the Combobox. You can use the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties of the combobox to indicate which properties from the NameDTO you want to see:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    names.Add( new NameDTO{ Id =2000, Name = "Ahemd"});
    names.Add(new NameDTO { Id = 5000, Name = "Omar" });
    names.Add(new NameDTO { Id = 4000, Name = "Mohamed" });

    comboBox1.DataSource = names;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
}
```

In your `SelectedIndexChanged` event you can now get hold of a NameDTO object in the `SelectedItem` property of the combobox.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   var si = (NameDTO) comboBox1.SelectedItem;
   nmstxtbx.Text = si.Name;
   // or the number is in  si.Id
}
```

To remove the selected item have a button with it its click event:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    names.Remove((NameDTO)comboBox1.SelectedItem);
}
```

Comment: there is no need to create own class - Dictionary has everything he needs